# Symfony getMethod() vs getRealMethod()

Tags: symfony, getmethod

I know the symfony api explain that getMethod() gets the request "intended" method and getRealMethod() gets the "real" request method but i can't figure out what "intended" and "real" means. 
Can anyone tell me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

`getRealMethod()` returns the **real** request method, while `getMethod()` returns the **intended** request method, which means the real request method is `POST` but symfony treat as others like `DELETE`.

See the example below:

```
<form method="post" action="..." >
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
  ...
</form>
```

The real request method is `POST`, while `getMethod()` will return `DELETE`.

Check the source:

```
/**
 * Gets the request "intended" method.
 *
 * If the X-HTTP-Method-Override header is set, and if the method is a POST,
 * then it is used to determine the "real" intended HTTP method.
 *
 * The _method request parameter can also be used to determine the HTTP method,
 * but only if enableHttpMethodParameterOverride() has been called.
 *
 * The method is always an uppercased string.
 *
 * @return string The request method
 *
 * @api
 *
 * @see getRealMethod
 */
public function getMethod()
{
    if (null === $this->method) {
        $this->method = strtoupper($this->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD', 'GET'));

        if ('POST' === $this->method) {
            if ($method = $this->headers->get('X-HTTP-METHOD-OVERRIDE')) {
                $this->method = strtoupper($method);
            } elseif (self::$httpMethodParameterOverride) {
                $this->method = strtoupper($this->request->get('_method', $this->query->get('_method', 'POST')));
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->method;
}

/**
 * Gets the "real" request method.
 *
 * @return string The request method
 *
 * @see getMethod
 */
public function getRealMethod()
{
    return strtoupper($this->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD', 'GET'));
}
```