# Difference between getMethod() and getRealMethod() in Symphony5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am not able to understand the difference between getMethod() and getRealMethod() in Symphony5.

I am using:

- Symfony 5
- PHP 7.4.3

I have already read through this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24115345/symfony-getmethod-vs-getrealmethod), but I am still facing strange issues.

What I want to achieve: Currently if I give an empty body to a
POST/PUT request then symfony gives a 500 Internal Server Error. But,
I want to give a 400 Bad Request Error to the user along with a custom
error message like "Empty request body with PUT/POST not allowed"

I have created this Request Listener,

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Exception;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class RequestListener
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function __invoke(RequestEvent $event): ?Response
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $method = $request->getMethod();
        $realMethod = $request->getRealMethod();

        // this echo below is just to know the values for $method and $realMethod for debugging
        echo("method = $method and real method = $realMethod");

        if (in_array($method, [Request::METHOD_POST, Request::METHOD_PUT]) && $request->get('data') === null) {
            $this->logger->info("Method PUT/POST with an empty body");
            return new Response(null, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

I have also added this Request Listener to the services.yaml file as,

```
App\EventListener\RequestListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener }
```

Now when I try to test this with postman I have the following response,

[image]

as you can see, the method I used is clearly shown as POST, symfony returns it as GET both for getMethod() and getRealMethod() (by the way, I am not sure why I get the echo message "method = GET and real method = GET" twice). And thus I am not able to check for the empty body for POST/PUT.

---

EDITED:

Running `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` gives this output:

```
"kernel.request" event
----------------------

 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                       Priority  
 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #1      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure()                  2048      
  #2      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ValidateRequestListener::onKernelRequest()          256       
  #3      Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest()                                250       
  #4      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()                  128       
  #5      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::setDefaultLocale()                  100       
  #6      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()                   32        
  #7      ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\QueryParameterValidateListener::onKernelRequest()               16        
  #8      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()                   16        
  #9      Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelRequest()              15        
  #10     Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::configureLogoutUrlGenerator()   8         
  #11     Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelRequest()               8         
  #12     ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\AddFormatListener::onKernelRequest()                            7         
  #13     ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\ReadListener::onKernelRequest()                                 4         
  #14     ApiPlatform\Core\Security\EventListener\DenyAccessListener::onSecurity()                       3         
  #15     ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\DeserializeListener::onKernelRequest()                          2         
  #16     ApiPlatform\Core\Security\EventListener\DenyAccessListener::onSecurityPostDenormalize()        1         
  #17     App\EventSubscriber\EmptyRequestBodySubscriber::handleEmptyRequestBody()                       1         
  #18     App\EventListener\RequestListener::__invoke()                                                  0         
  #19     ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Bundle\EventListener\SwaggerUiListener::onKernelRequest()      0         
 ------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

As you can see, my listener is found registered at #18,

```
#18     App\EventListener\RequestListener::__invoke()                                                  0
```

Comment: Not all browsers can generate all http methods (PUT,DELETE etc) so there are ways to make a POST method pretend to be a different method.  None of which seems applicable to your case.  Your images make it difficult to figure out exactly what you are doing but it's clear you have something else going on.  Might want to double check that your listener is registered as expected with bin/console debug:event-dispatcher

Comment: @Cerad I ran `bin/console debug:event-dispatcher` and found my listener at #18,(for verbose output please the EDITED part of the question above), so I think that my listener is registered correctly. "Your images make it difficult to figure out exactly what you are doing" => please suggest how can I provide a better picture to you about my issue.

Comment: `__invoke()` must return `Response` or `null`. Now it returns `void`. Just add `return null;` after that if

Comment: As mentioned above, a simple return null might get you past the current error.  You might also have to adjust your listener's priority.  Something like POST /api/login will probably get handled by the security system before reaching your listener.  And just showing what you tried to post and a few lines of the resulting error message would have been easier to read than trying to interpret some image.